# Why use nested blocks?

Tags: rust

I just came across this piece of code in base64 crate:

```
 buffer.resize(decoded_len_estimate, 0);

let bytes_written;
{
    let buffer_slice = &mut buffer.as_mut_slice()[starting_output_len..];
    bytes_written = decode_helper(input_bytes, num_chunks, config, buffer_slice)?;
}

buffer.truncate(starting_output_len + bytes_written);
```

See https://github.com/marshallpierce/rust-base64/blob/b63975f0a3d2e724c611bf6cd7213ae6bcb065a3/src/decode.rs#L165-L169

What is the reason for using this style of declaring the variable bytes_written and then use this nested block. What problem does this solve? Why not just use this code:

```
 buffer.resize(decoded_len_estimate, 0);

let buffer_slice = &mut buffer.as_mut_slice()[starting_output_len..];
let bytes_written = decode_helper(input_bytes, num_chunks, config, buffer_slice)?  
buffer.truncate(starting_output_len + bytes_written);
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: One reason is that it prevents `buffer_slice` from leaking out into the outer namespace.

Comment: For one thing, they limit the scope of variables, and sometimes are necessary due to how the compiler treats lifetimes. As for why they are used in that specific instance, I don't know, because it doesn't seem to actually be necessary (the code still compiles without them).

Comment: One reason not shown here is that if you have a variable that only needs to be mutable during setup and then should be immutable thereafter, you can perform setup inside the block and then assign an immutable variable to the block's "return value".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This code was written 4 years ago ([5 Dec 2017](https://github.com/marshallpierce/rust-base64/commit/0113a0529baccc4cf3b7a305c8a553c36f6d1d78#diff-aeece9508d349335fdebc30632ef26fa2851aa73336dea735c78d36cb7e77b2bR139-R145)), before [NLL](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html) (Non-Lexical Lifetimes) arrived ([6 Dec 2018](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#non-lexical-lifetimes)). With NLL, the borrow checker consider a reference "alive" until its last use and no more. But without it, a reference is considered alive until the end of the scope (its drop). Since `buffer_slice` borrows `buffer` mutably, and the last line does that too, the borrow checker pre-NLL would err - and that's probably why they introduced the block, to create a new scope for `buffer_slice` so it will be dropped before the next borrow of `buffer`.